# my trigger is not updating parent object record

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

i am creating three child records when a record is created on parent object using process builder. now,  i am writing a trigger to update 'status__c = closed' field on parent object when status of three child record's is marked as 'completed'. 
below is my apex method

```
public class StatusClosedHandler { 
    public static void statuschange(List<Id> RecordId){ 
        integer count = 0; 
        List<Service_Request__c> srequest = new List<Service_Request__c>();
        for(Service_Line__c sl : [Select id, Name, Status__c,Line_Type__c, Service_Request__r.Status__c,Service_Request__r.Name from Service_Line__c WHERE Service_Request__c = :RecordId[i] ]){
            if(sl.Status__c == 'Completed'){ 
                count++;
            } 
            if(count == 3){
                Service_Request__c sr = new Service_Request__c();
                sr.id = sl.Service_Request__c;
                sr.status__c = 'Closed';
                srequest.add(sr);
            } 
        }

        update srequest;
    } 
}
```

and my trigger to call this method is :

```
trigger StatusClosedfinal on Service_Line__c (after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){ 
        List<Id> sLine = new List<Id>();
        for(Service_Line__c  i:trigger.new) {
            sLine.add(i.Id);
        }
        StatusClosedHandler.statuschange(sLine); 
    } 
}
```

when i am running method in anonymous window and passing parent id as a list, it's updating the status, but not while runnig the trigger.
​​​​​​​please help

Comment: In `:RecordId[i]`, what is `i`? don't do SOQLs inside a loop (as part of the for its ok, but the `[i]` would suggest you are iterating somewhere and increasing the value of `i`

Comment: Please ignore that, intially i was running a loop to query based on the record id count but that wasn't a right approach, i forgot to edit that. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is unnecessary in your trigger

```
List<Id> sLine = new List<Id>();
for(Service_Line__c  i:trigger.new) {
   sLine.add(i.Id);
}
```

Simply pass `trigger.new` to the handler and change the handler's method signature

`public static void statuschange(List<Service_Line__c> ServiceLines){`

After that, you would not need to have the SOQL with `for` and it would be

`for(Service_Line__c serviceline: ServiceLines){`

---

Other thing that could be related to your problem is `Service_Request__c` fields are not queried. You should run a soql on `Service_Request__c` and put them in a `map` with SErviceRequestId as key.
`SELECT id, Status, ... otherfields FROM Service_Request__c WHERE id in [ServiceRequestIds_frm_Service_Lines]`
(You can build Service request id from service lines by looping through)

**Basic update to your handler class will be**

```
public class StatusClosedHandler { 
    public static void statuschangeList<Service_Line__c> ServiceLines){ 
       Set<Id> servicerequestIds = new Set<Id>();
       for(Serivce_Line__c sl: ServiceLines) servicerequestIds.add(sl.Service_Request__c);
       // query service request records
       Map<Id, Service_request__c> servicerequestmap = New Map<Id, Service_REquest__c>([SELECT Id, Status FROM Service_Request__c WHERE Id in: servicerequestids]);
        integer count = 0; 
        List<Service_Request__c> srequest = new List<Service_Request__c>();
        for(Service_Line__c sl : ServiceLines]){
            if(sl.Status__c == 'Completed'){ 
                count++;                     
            } 
            if(count == 3){
                Service_Request__c sr = servicerequestmap.get(sl.Service_Request__c);
                sr.status__c = 'Closed';
                srequest.add(sr);
            } 
        }

        update srequest;
    } 
}
```

### Edit

Problem: Parent should be completed when all children `status` are completed.

**Solution**

1. Best solution here would be, to have a custom field `Children completed` field (boolean) on Service_Request__c and increment it each time a child `status` is completed.
2. Have process builder on `Service Request` object, and check if the counter is 3, then set the `status` to completed.

   `if(sl.Status__c == 'Completed'){ 
         Service_Request__c sr = servicerequestmap.get(sl.Service_Request__c);
         sr.Children_Completed__c += 1;
         srequest.add(sr);
       }`

and below `if` condition will not be required then.

### 2nd edit

Just been thinking about your updated requirements,  a trigger itself seems unnecessary now. :-)

You just need two process builders ,

1. one on ServiceLine , check status, and if completed, increment parent's 'children completed' fields.
2. Second process builder on service request, and check if the 'children completed' counter is 3, then update its status to completed.

Comment: Thank you so much mate but here it's a master-detail relationship
do you think this query would work?
for(Service_Request__c sr: [Select id, Status__c, (select id, Status__c from Service_Lines__r) FROM Service_Request__c WHERE id in [ServiceRequestIds_frm_Service_Lines]])

Comment: Why do you want to have the above query? You are updating `status` of parent i.e.`Service_request__c` and that's all. You don't need the above query.

Comment: you mean i should be doing a normal query like this
List<Status_Request__c> sRequest = [SELECT id, Status__c FROM Service_Request__c WHERE id in [ServiceRequestIds_frm_Service_Lines]

Comment: No. Please check my code that I provided. Above I created a `Map` `(Map<Id, Service_request__c> servicerequestmap = New Map<Id, Service_REquest__c>([SELECT Id, Status FROM Service_Request__c WHERE Id in: servicerequestids]);)` and ServiceRequestIds were created earlier.

Comment: ServiceRequestIds were created using this code `for(Serivce_Line__c sl: ServiceLines) servicerequestIds.add(sl.Service_Request__c);`

Comment: for both the 'for each loop on Service_Line__c' it's throwing the same error
"Invalid loop variable type expected Service_Request__c was Service_Line__c"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The method signature was incorrect, I should have used `public static void statuschangeList<Service_Line__c> ServiceLines){ `. :)

Comment: this seems fine but Parent status is updating only when all the 3 child status is set to 'completed' simultaneously otherwise not. what if the status of three records are getting updated one by one?. it would be very appreciatable if  you cloud look into this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? What is the requirement? When do you want to update parent obj `status` ?

Comment: okay so there are three child records for each parent(Service Request) record. all the records are associated with three Line Types(Line A Type, Line B Type, Line C Type) all the three line types records are basically coming from a picklist field Line_Type__c

Comment: for each Line_Type__c field there are three records. on updating of the status of these three line type, the parent record needs to be updated

Comment: The final code is doing it fine but only when these three child records are updating  simultaneously, i want to update parent record when these child records are updating even one by one. did you get the clarity now??

Comment: Then simply use `if(sl.Status__c == 'Completed'){ ` then update the parent like
`Service_Request__c sr = servicerequestmap.get(sl.Service_Request__c);
                sr.status__c = 'Closed';
                srequest.add(sr);` 
So, even a single child is completed, parent status will also be completed.

Comment: Well, i want all three service lines to be 'completed' then only service request to be closed. but with the earlier solution the service request is getting closed only when i am updating three line type simultaneously . when i am updatig it individually, it's not working

Comment: Placed an `Edit` block in my response. Please check.

Comment: @MikeT please see my 2nd edit. You probably dont  need a trigger at all.